# Нужна помощь с формированием хедеров patch запроса python

Tags: python, requests

Имеются хедеры запроса в разделе Network хрома.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я подчеркнул обязательные поля хедеров, однако, я получаю 400 код ошибки, в котором говорится, что отсутсвует body запроса.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в разделе Network еще есть payload -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я думаю, что это и есть body, однако как я не пытался впихнуть этот body в headers, мне все равно давали ошибку 403, с тем жем описанием.

Comment: Payload похож на JSON, так что его скорее нужно поместить в [аргумент json](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp) метода POST.

Comment: Сервер не принимает POST запрос, только PATCH и несколько других